# Rebooting raspi out of external javascript (HTML) in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, shell, raspberry-pi

Im running a html webpage on a raspberry pi.

From there i give the value of some checkbockes (form) to a external .js-File.
Now i want to write the results of the form into a .txt on the raspberry and read it after reboot. Later the pi will install some packages depending on what the .txt includes / what checkboxes have been ticked before.

I tried to run shell-commands inside the called .js, maybe something like "echo >>" to write the variables to the text file. But i cant get shell-commands running, i have  tested with "sudo reboot" just for simplicity.

My "vartofile.js":

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

function save_installform()
{
    var bluetooth=document.forms["installform"]["bluetooth"].checked;
    var upnp=document.forms["installform"]["upnp"].checked;
    var airplay=document.forms["installform"]["airplay"].checked;
    var snapcast=document.forms["installform"]["snapcast"].checked;
    var spotify=document.forms["installform"]["spotify"].checked;
    alert("Bluetooth: " + bluetooth + " | UPnP: " + upnp + " | Airplay: " + airplay + " | Spotify: " + spotify + " | Snapcast: " + snapcast);


    exec("sudo reboot", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (!error) console.log("... restarting OS!");
        else console.log("... restarting OS failed! - " + stdout);
    });
};
```

The alert-line works and gives me the true values of all variables given in the html. I therefore have not included the html-code because i think it works so far.

**I just want the damn thing to restart after it has given the alert.**

Wish you the best